# Working with multiple DbContext instances causes wrong values to be loaded from database Entity Framework Core

Tags: api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core API in which the dependency injection container provides me with instances of my `DbContext` class. I set the service lifetime of the `DbContext` to transient (which means that the container will create a new instance for every class and every request).

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ComparisonInfoContext>(dbContextOptions => 
dbContextOptions.UseSqlServer("Connection string"), ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Here is my `DbContext` class:

```
 public class ComparisonInfoContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ComparisonInfo> Comparisons { get; set; } = null!;

        public ComparisonInfoContext(DbContextOptions<ComparisonInfoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ComparisonInfo>().OwnsMany(c => c.DiscrepancyInfos);
        }
    }
```

I also have a `BackgroundService` class  called `JobChecker` which I added by calling:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<JobChecker>();
```

In `JobChecker`, I have a function that runs every minute and the first thing that function does is call `context.Comparisons.ToListAsync()`. The first time the function runs everything works fine, but the second time, this call returns outdated values for some reason (The values it returns used to be in the database but were changed prior to this call being made).

What I think is happening is the following:

1. `JobChecker` (the BackgroundService class) receives it's instance of `DbContext` at the very start of the program.
2. The function inside `JobChecker` calls `context.Comparisons.ToListAsync()` and gets the correct values from the database (no problems here).
3. Some controller somewhere changes the values in the database using it's own instance of the `DbContext`.
4. The function inside `JobChecker` runs and calls `context.Comparisons.ToListAsync()`. It sees that it is already tracking instances with the same `id` which came from the previous call (step 2). These instances were not effected by the changes made by the controller in step 3. It does not materialize the values it got from the database, instead it returns the instances that already exist. This is explained more here: [The life of a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works)

Does anyone know whether this is in fact what is happening? Is it even correct to set the service lifetime of the `DbContext class` to transient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DB Context might be transient, but the `BackgroundService` is not. In effect you only have a single instance of the context in the `BackgroundService`.

I would look at injecting in an DB Context Factory:

```cs
services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(...)
```

Then inject one into your background service:

```cs
public class MyBackgroundService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory)
```

Then every iteration of your loop in the background service (it sounds like it is running on a timer), you can use this to instantiate a new context.

```cs
using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

Answer (score 1):

I once faced the same problem with you ,and finally fixed it follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task):

```
public SomeBackgroundService( IServiceProvider services)
        {
            ......
        }


using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<BackgroundServiceProjContext>();
                var personlist1 = context?.Person.ToList();
            }
```

I modified the name and  the context injected directly into backgroundservice  still read the former value:
[image]